# how to change Time format?

Tags: asp.net, datetime, formatting

How to fatch `Hours:minutes`  from a datetime variable. Right I am using Strings function to achieve this. Is there any builtin function for this?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=VS.90).aspx#Y1700 ... Point to note, "h:m" will return the time in 12hour format, while "H:m" will return in 24hour format ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
yourdt.ToString("h:m");
```

for current time

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("h:m");
```

Answer (score 1):

for showing time in hh:mm you can format like this

```
date.ToString("hh:mm");
```

Comment: would it hurt someone to answer why my answer is downvoted where i am wrong atleast tell me that